# use of ffmpeg select filter

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, video-editing

I am stuck with the use of ffmpeg select filter as I want to pick up only the ending frame of a input video but I cannot figure out the selection expression for the filter to get the work done, 
my code looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4  -filter_complex  "select=expr_selecting_lastest_frame, overlay=overlay_expr"  out.jpg
```

now how do I coding the expr_selecting_lastest_frame ? 
do you guys have ideas ? 
is there any other way to get the work done ? please help, thank you !

Comment: You only have one input. What are you overlaying with?

Comment: hi, Gyan, thank you for comment ,  I would use a more complicated filter-chain expression  in my actual work ,  but in my question , please just focus on the 'select' filter

Comment: You cannot do this using select filter. Select filter has different applications, it is used to compare subsequent frames in a video and compute their difference values. I think you will have to extract the frame by frame number or duration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use ffprobe to get the total frame count and assign it to a var

```
$frame_count="$(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams v:0 -count_frames -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -of csv=p=0 in.mp4)";
```

use the var in select filter

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "select='eq(n,$frame_count)'" -vframes 1 out.jpg
```

or the 2nd to the last frame

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "select='eq(n,$frame_count-1)'" -vframes 1 out.jpg
```

Comment: I was expecting to find a method that can accomplish the  goal by writing only a single line command , but it seams to be  impossible ,  thank you all the same .

Answer (score 2):

For formats with known duration and a global header, like MP4 or MKV, you can do

```
ffmpeg -sseof -3 -i file -vsync 0 -q:v 1 -update true out.jpg
```

`sseof` seeks from the end - I've used a value of 3, to account for files with longer audio streams. `-update` is an image2 muxer option which tells ffmpeg to overwrite the output file. So the last time the output will be overwritten is when the last frame is processed.